# How to check if a cJSON pointer was initialized/set earlier?

Tags: cjson

I have  a struct with cJSON pointers as in:

```
  struct { 

      cJSON *myJSON1;
      cJSON *myJSON2;
      ...
  } myStruct;
```

Somewhere in my code I create cJSON items as in  myStruct.myJSON1 = cJSON_CreateObject()

At the end of the code, I want to call cJSON_Delete() on those pointers which were assigned. I presume this is the classic C case where there is no way to find out if the pointer was malloced in some way. Of course, I can keep a flag to keep track but I want a simple way. I read...

The cJSON struct is as:

```
  /* The cJSON structure: */
  typedef struct cJSON
  {
      struct cJSON *next;
      struct cJSON *prev;
      struct cJSON *child;
      int type;
      char *valuestring;
      /* writing to valueint is DEPRECATED, use cJSON_SetNumberValue instead */
      int valueint;
      double valuedouble;
      char *string;
  } cJSON;
```

The function *cJSON_Invalid()* is available. The documentation states "(check with cJSON_IsInvalid): Represents an invalid item that doesn't contain any value. You automatically have this type if you set the item to all zero bytes." Do I have to memset the structure to 0 or just type?

In other words, my question is: What would be the easiest way to check if a cJSON pointer is malloced without creating an additional variable? Perhaps set "type" to zero? I can try such options but I want a definite answer which works in all situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have an uninitialized pointer to a cJSON data structure the behavior is undefined. 
I.e. for `cJSON *myJSON1;`

`cJSON_Invalid(myJSON1)` might return `0` or `1`.

And `cJSON_Delete(myJSON1)` will probably segfault. Or do nothing if you get lucky.

The solution is to always initialize cJSON data structures to `NULL`. 
Then you can just call `cJSON_Delete()`. If the pointer is still `NULL` the call will do nothing. If it was set up at some point in your program it will correctly release all the memory.
Since you have a structure of multiple `cJSON` pointers you can set the entire data structure to `0` using memset.

You can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON/blob/master/cJSON.c).

```
CJSON_PUBLIC(void) cJSON_Delete(cJSON *item)
{
    cJSON *next = NULL;
    while (item != NULL)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @hkp cJSON_Invalid() actually segfaults for me when not initialized. I think now that that makes sense because there is no way for the function to know if it was initialized.